# How rebuild webform after ajax submit?

Tags: 7, ajax, webforms

I am using Webform with AJAX module. I have added the Webform in block and submit it via AJAX. All I want to do is open new form after getting confirmation message without reloading whole page and without clicking "Go back to form".

How to do Go back to form automatic after 5 sec for example?

Comment: Would having a multi-step form solve this for you? Can you explain what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: It seems you haven't configures Ajax correctly. You wouldn't go to "Go back to form" page otherwise.

Comment: I have a webworm in block, after it submission on screen shown confirm message and link "Go back to form". When I click link form rebooting and I can fill the form again and submit it. I want form rebooting automatic after confirm message shown. Is it possible?